# Mysql break long query in multiple line queries

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, liquibase

I use the MySQL docker container to develop an application.
My application connects successfully to MYSQL and executes queries appropriately.

My problem comes in when I want to execute a multiple-line query on it.

For example:

```
-- liquibase format sql
--changeset alipour:13990724_1
select host,
   user,
   Select_priv
from user
where 1=1;
```

After executing the query I got the below error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 2: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '--changeset alipour:13990724_1
select host,
   user,
   Select_priv
from' at line 1
```

Ways I checked but got the same error:

- used `allowMultiQueries=true` on Datasource URL
- saved the query in a file and I tested it by MySQL command

I use spring boot in my application with liquibase for database evolution.

Comment: The error message is not consistent with the query: it mentions `--changeset alipour:13990724_1`, which does not appear in the query.

Comment: @GMB Thank you for your reply, `--changeset alipour:13990724_1` is liquibase sql file format that should be in first.

Comment: @GMB You right, I should add a space between `--` and `changeset`, the correct syntax is `-- changeset alipour:13990724_1 `.  this took an hour of my time. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a   caused the problem.

Thank you @GMB for your tip.

I changed

```
--changeset alipour:13990724_1
```

to

```
-- changeset alipour:13990724_1
```

and the problem solved.